# Sound playing program

Tags: winforms, audio, c#-4.0

I need to write an application C# where a list of songs is loaded and the component would play the songs in the order of the list throwing numerous events like song position and others, and basically have an automatic fader between the list's songs based say on some custom seconds...

How to I build this?

Comment: @closers - it's just a question about using SDK.

Comment: What is the point of your question?

Comment: I just seek any component making this jobs, whats so big deal and be so negative? Isn't that inside the boundaries of developing?

Comment: @gtas: Seems like your question can easily be gotten misunderstood. I haven't voted you down and choose to ask. So what I understood is you need to write an app and that app needs alot of features other existing media player apps also have but you need your own and therefore you need a basis. This is a good question I agree. In first reading it sound strange like: "I want to re-invent the wheel and need a good example". But as said, you meant something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows Media Player SDK for this and write your own wrapper around it.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/playerforpros.mspx

Several other players offer SDKs that you can integrate into your own application as well.